# Fullcalendar events render from DB without regard to timezone

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I currently have a fullcalendar application that I've set up using PHP and MYSQL (AWS RDS).

Event start and end times are stored in the database as strings looking like `Fri Mar 29 2019 09:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`, which come from the `event.start` and `event.end` properties.

Then, they are loaded using load.php (called by `events: load.php`), which looks like:

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';

$conn = $dbConnection;
$query = "SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY id";

$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();

$data = $statement->fetchAll();
$results = array();

foreach($data as $row) {
    $results[] = array(
        'id'   => $row["id"],
        'title'   => $row["title"],
        'resourceId' => $row["resource"],
        'start'   => $row["start_event"],
        'end'   => $row["end_event"]
    );
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

At this point, they display; however, they always display 7 hours ahead of when they are supposed to (e.g. `09:00:00` turns into `16:00:00`).

I assume this is because when the data comes from the database, it is neglecting the timezone in some way, but when I change the timezone using `timezone: 'UTC'`, nothing happens.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated, and thanks!

Comment: What data type are the `start_event` and `end_event` columns?

Comment: @Nick Strings - it's not optimal but I wasn't sure how to parse them properly

Comment: @Nick That's probably the root of the problem.  I'm going to look into ways to convert strings into dates before they go into the db.

Comment: You probably want to look into the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. You might be able to use that to convert the data on output too. Is `Fri Mar 29 2019 09:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)` the exact format of your strings?

Comment: @Nick That is the format.  I just looked at the class and tried using it, although I'm a bit new new to PHP and honestly have no idea how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your date strings are in the format as you describe in your question e.g.

```
Fri Mar 29 2019 09:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

You should be able to parse them into `DateTime` objects using [`date_create_from_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) e.g.

```
$date_string = 'Fri Mar 29 2019 09:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)';
$date = date_create_from_format('D M d Y H:i:s \G\M\TO+', $date_string);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output:

```
2019-03-29 09:00:00
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/sIUOb)

Comment: I've tried implementing this; however, when I upload it to AWS and use it I get an error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean`, which I'm having trouble understanding.  The code can be seen here: https://3v4l.org/kUDsJ

Comment: @Rescis can you add `if ($start === false) echo DateTime::getLastErrors();` (and the same for `$end`) and see what it says? Also if you can echo the failing date string that would be helpful.

Comment: Right now insert.php is being called via jquery ajax - do you know of an equivalent for echo if It's set up as such?

Comment: @Rescis if you're returning any data you could wrap all your code in an `ob_start()` and then add something like `'output' => ob_get_clean()` to your return data and then alert that in the jQuery.

Comment: I got it fixed.  The problem was that `end` was empty, and then  `date_create_from_format` threw an error saying so (in a sort of weird fashion).